# Where do I put the C wire in this setup

Tags: thermostat-c-wire

Got me a wefe thermostat. Old thermostat used 4 wires but the blue C was stuffed in the wall. I have read many forums and nobodys setup really matches mine.
[image]

This what I see at the furnace and what I think the functions are. I see the spot for C but it has a red and yellow wire connected to it. I figured T would be the common but when I hooked the blue wire to this I got power to my new thermostat and could make the fan come on but the A/C would not turn on. Guess my only question being is where to put the darn C wire. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the old tstat and setup in the furnace. I cannot see a model anywhere on it. Just says climatrol. It is an older one tho with a pilot I gotta light manually.

[image]

[image]

Here is the wifi stat setup.[image]

I turned it back on and afew minutes later while uploading this pic it the system came on!!! Musta took 3 to 5 minutes but its working! Will make sure it does what it is suppose to do but thank you for advice on waiting and the other help you provided. I really appreciate it!!!

Comment: Can you post a picture of the actual wiring inside your furnace? What's the make/model of the furnace? Can you post a picture of the old t-stat?

Comment: There is the setup. Mess of wires inside the air handler but the picture i drew gives the layout and the letters on the board. Not sure why the Heat is white on the air handler and brown when it gets to the thermostat.

Comment: I think T might be common as well. You could test it with a volt meter to be sure (voltage between V and T should read 24 if V is indeed power - test between V and ground to make sure). How long did you wait for A/C to come on? Sometimes there's a significant delay from fan on to cooling. Can you post a picture of how you wired your WiFi stat?

Comment: There is 24 between V and ground as well as V and T. I waited about a minute or two. When i set the thermostat to cool and and fan to auto it clicked but nothing happened. When i set the fan to on the fan came on but not the outside unit. So i set the fan back to auto and after about a minute the fan shutoff. Will get a pic of how I wired the stat when my internet quits being dumb. I wired it the way it said to. In the manual. Only thing different from the old was the new blue common wire and i put that in thr C spot

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. It looks like you now have [two](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/104094/eric) separate [accounts](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/104095/eric); you should [request that they be merged](//diy.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts). And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

T is common, confirmed by reading 24VAC across T and V (24VAC should also exist across V and ground to confirm V as hot). A/C may need a few minutes to kick on.